# average real variability (ARV) index of blood pressure, how to edit this formula in r or python

Tags: python, r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeixN.png)
I'm calculating the average real variability (ARV) index of blood pressure, how to edit this formula in r or python, thx a lot

Comment: Hi Sandy. Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and see [ask]. While we do help with coursework, we are not a general programming forum or a free code-writing service. Please do the necessary [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), make an earnest attempt on a specific stack (Python or R, not both), and come back with specific issues regarding your trial such as errors or undesired results.